# How can I add a header folder to my project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm developing an iOS application with latest Xcode 4.5.2.

I have the following folder structure:

```
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName.xcodeproject
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/xxx.m
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/xxx.h
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/PVRT/
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/PVRT/header1.h
/.../SourceCode/MyProjectFolder/projectName/PVRT/OtherFolder/header2.h
```

If in my header files I add this:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

I get a `"header1.h" not found error.`

But, if I add:

```
#include "PVRT/header1.h"
```

I get a `"header2.h" not found.`

On project settings I have add the following path:

```
${SOURCE_ROOT}/projectName/PVRT
```

But I'm getting the same error.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust "Header Search Path" values in build settings of target & set according to your project's header file paths.
Hope it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Build settings' of your target, search for 'Header Search Paths'. In the highest field (so before 'Debug' and 'Release') type in the following line:

```
"$(SRCROOT)"/**
```

This will add your entire source directory to the header search path. You can always expand the path if you want to include specific folders.